# HTML / Javascript not working in IE only Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm having issues with some javascript that I'm wanting to put on our local intranet site for staff to see.  Essntially what it does is pulls the staff birthdays from an array and if their birthday is today, then it shows their birthday on the site.  The problem is that the code I have is working perfectly in Chrome, but in IE it is showing "- None" even when a birthday matches today's date.

Thanks for the help guys.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var arrBday = [
['Erica As','5/1'],
['Jacob C','5/4'],
['Rheann A','5/5'],
['Kim K','5/7'],
['James R','5/9'],
['Lee R','5/9'],
['Ryan W','5/13'],
['Angie E','5/19'],
['Eric H','5/22'],
['Gary B','5/24'],
['Jason T','5/24'],
['Kevin B','5/30'],
['Luis M','5/30'],
['Dale B','5/31']
];

function displayBdayList(today){
var bday,strList='';
for (var i=0;i<arrBday.length;i++){
bday = new Date(arrBday[i][1]);
if (!isNaN(bday) && bday.getMonth()==today.getMonth() && bday.getDate()==today.getDate()) 
strList+='- '+arrBday[i][0]+" <br>";
}
if (strList=='') strList='- None'
document.write("Today's Staff Birtdays:<br>"+strList)
}

displayBdayList(new Date());
</script>
```

Comment: Could be the `language="JavaScript"` attribute, which was deprecated 20 years ago ?

Comment: Are you saying I should just leave it <script>?

Comment: Could also be that IE doesn't support the totally invalid `5/24` dates you're passing to `new Date` ?

Comment: That was it! I added the year to the birthdays, and IE started working.  Thanks man!

Comment: Could be a "not enough whitespace" error. Or an "invasion of employee privacy" error.

Comment: Could also be that John was left out, and won't be congratulated on his birthday ?

Comment: @adeneo Your suggestion fixed my issue. IE doesn't like the 5/24 format.

Comment: Of course it doesn't, valid arguments for the date constructor is `new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);`, not random strings made up of numbers and slashes.